# create screen with horizonal and vertical scroll of portion

Tags: listview, flutter, row, flutter-layout, scrollable

I want to create this type of screen in flutter but don't know how to create it.

Functionality is like **my categories are sticky to left side as column and my slabs like 1000-5000 are sticky in horizontal row, and other portion is scrollable vertical or horizontal**.

So when I scroll inner part vertically my category section should scroll with it, When I scroll inner part horizontal my slabs should scroll with it.

I hope you get my issue.

[image: Image here]

Comment: Use this https://github.com/luodongseu/flutter_sticky_table

Comment: @SandipSavaliya 